# Colouring a cell in a data grid that has ItemSource set to a Data table

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a data table that is viewed on a data grid by specifying the ItemsSource property of the data grid as

```
this.heatMap.ItemsSource = heatMapTable.DefaultView;
```

Where heatmap is the DataGrid and heatMapTable is the DataTable.
My question is how is it possible to select a cell from this data grid and color it at a particular condition. i know that i can't colour the data table. Please help..

Comment: You can write a style for DataGridCell to apply the background color based on DataTrigger.

Comment: no, at a specifc condition for example i want to color all the cells of the   DataRow in the DataTable to yellow if the cell contains the content "y".

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTriggers to check for your condition. Eg;

```
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Area}" Value="12345">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: i got an error  "items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource" what to do?

Comment: How you are using the DataGrid, show the XAML code.